# Pod accepting socket connection cannot see initiating pod's IP, if located on different kubernetes nodes

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes

System: kubernetes cluster running on vagrant using virtualbox 
Pod A: 10.246.79.2 on minion 2 
Pod B: 10.246.61.3 on minion 3 
Pod C: 10.246.61.2 on minion 3

When a container in Pod C accepts a socket connection from Pod A, it sees the peer socket IP as 10.246.79.0, which happens to be the IP address of the flannel0 interface on minion 2.

Is there something wrong with my network configuration? I used the defaults that came with vagrant.

UPDATE:
Actually, I found that the problem is due to IP Masquerading.  I found this in iptables:

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)  
num  target     prot opt source               destination          
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.246.79.0/24       0.0.0.0/0

However, I thought flannel was set up with masquerading turned off: 
[vagrant@kubernetes-minion-2 ~]$ cat /run/flannel/subnet.env  
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.246.79.1/24  
FLANNEL_MTU=1472  
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=false

So I'm still confused...

Answer (score 1):

The kube-proxy also uses IP tables.
Are you using services to communicate between Pods?

Comment: I do have a service but in this case, Pod A requests a socket connection directly using Pod C's IP address, rather than through the service. The pods need to communicate with each other directly so going through a service is out of the question.